# Leaflet - how to show both PHOTO and URL in the popup at same time?

Tags: url, leaflet, photo

I'm having Leaflet trouble combining code to show **both a photo and a URL in my popup**. Ideally, I want the photo to be linked to the URL so clicking on it takes the visitor to the page of the URL.

So far, this is my code that works for them separately:

```
**URL**:
                if (feature.properties.url) {
                html += '<a href="' + feature.properties.url + '"  target="_blank">Site Internet</a></br>';
            }

 **PHOTO**:
                if (feature.properties.picture) {
                html += '<img src="'+ feature.properties.picture +'" style="width:200px;height:200px;">'+ '</br>';
            }
```

Can someone please advise how to combine the two to one command?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will display the picture as a link to the url if the picture exists. You can add more logic to cater for the URL not existing.

```
    if (feature.properties.url) {
        html += '<a href="' + feature.properties.url + '"  target="_blank">';

        if (feature.properties.picture) {
                    html += '<img src="'+ feature.properties.picture +'" style="width:200px;height:200px;">'+ '</a></br>';
        } 
        else {  
             html += 'Site Internet</a></br>';
         }
    }
```